# Difference between suspend to "mem" and pm-suspend

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management, acpi

What is the difference between

```
echo "mem" > /sys/power/state
```

and

```
pm-suspend
```

Both can put the computer to sleep mode. I want to execute a script automatically when the system resumes from sleep. I wrote a script and put it in /etc/pm/sleep.d. It works only when I use pm-suspend command and resume the system back. However, it has no effect on resume if I suspend the system with *echo "mem" > /sys/power/state*. I also noticed that pm-suspend takes a bit longer than *echo "mem" ...*.

Comment: This is a good question. I'd like to know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Same same, but different.

On my ubuntu system pm-suspend ends up doing the same:

```
do_suspend() { echo -n "mem" >/sys/power/state; }
```

But as you have noted pm-suspend wraps a whole lot of other stuff around the call for management of the process like logging, locking, error checking, debug and the hooks you are using.

```
vi /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

and

```
$ grep '()'  "/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions"
log()
profiling() { [ "$PM_PROFILE" = "true" ]; }
        profile() {
        profile() { shift; "$@"; }
add_before_hooks() {
add_module_help() {
before_hooks()
sleep_module_help()
update_parameters()
load_hook_blacklist()
load_hook_parameters()
hook_exit_status(){
hook_ok()
_run_hook() {
        # log() changes the return value, so save it for later
        run_hook() { profile "$1:" _run_hook "$@"; }
        run_hook() { _run_hook "$@"; }
_run_hooks() {
        run_hooks() { profile "$1 $2:" _run_hooks "$@"; }
        run_hooks() { _run_hooks "$@"; }
init_logfile()
check_suspend() { [ -n "$SUSPEND_MODULE" ]; }
check_hibernate() { [ -n "$HIBERNATE_MODULE" ]; }
check_suspend_hybrid() { [ -n "$SUSPEND_HYBRID_MODULE" ]; }
check_suspend_pmu()
do_suspend_pmu()
                do_suspend() { echo -n "mem" >/sys/power/state; }
                do_suspend() { do_suspend_pmu; }
                do_suspend() { echo -n "standby" >/sys/power/state; }
        do_hibernate()
    do_suspend_hybrid() {
```

for even lower level, check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658170/how-ther-linux-kernel-process-the-write-to-sys-power-state